# Ubuntu 13.10 install VMware 9.0

Tags: vmware

After I install the VMware workstation 9.0, while when I want open the VM, there come the dialogue "Before you can run VMware, several modules must be complied and loaded into the running kernel CANCEL INSTALL",while I clicked the INSTALL button, nothing happened.

When:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic
sudo /usr/bin/vmware-modconfig --icon=vmware-workstation --appname=VMware
```

come:

```
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-T9k19t/vmci-only/linux/driver.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-T9k19t/vmci-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic'
make: *** [vmci.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-T9k19t/vmci-only'
Failed to build vmci.  Failed to execute the build command.
Starting VMware services:
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
   Virtual machine communication interface                            failed
   VM communication interface socket family                            done
   Blocking file system                                                done
   Virtual ethernet                                                   failed
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Download the three files as mentioned in the bottom Ref:

   - When running kernel 3.10:

     - [procfs.patch](https://communities.vmware.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/2281917-112737/procfs.patch)
     - [vmblock.3.10.patch](https://communities.vmware.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/2281917-112712/vmblock.3.10.patch)
   - When running kernel 3.11, apply the following extra patch as well:

     - [vmblock.3.11.patch](https://communities.vmware.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/2281917-112711/vmblock.3.11.patch)
2. Thereafter, execute the code making necessary modifications:

   ```
   $ cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
   $ sudo tar -xf vmnet.tar
   $ sudo tar -xf vmblock.tar
   $ cd vmnet-only
   $ sudo patch -p1 < <Patch path>/procfs.patch
   $ cd ../vmblock-only
   $ sudo patch -p1 < <Patch path>/vmblock.3.10.patch
   $ sudo patch -p1 < <Patch path>/vmblock.3.11.patch
   $ cd ..
   $ sudo tar -cf vmblock.tar vmblock-only
   $ sudo tar -cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
   $ sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
   ```

---

Ref: the [solution](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2308156) by [Rainmaker52](https://communities.vmware.com/people/Rainmaker52).

Comment: @Aditya,Sorry, I am newer, have edited. Thanks for your kind mention.

Comment: @Aditya, Thanks, I download three files through clicking the attaching links([procfs.patch](https://communities.vmware.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/2281917-112737/procfs.patch), [vmblock.3.10.patch](https://communities.vmware.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/2281917-112712/vmblock.3.10.patch), [vmblock.3.11.patch](https://communities.vmware.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/2281917-112711/vmblock.3.11.patch)), not the links in the guide content from the referring solution by Rainmaker52.

Comment: @Aditya. Great, thanks for your patience and kindly help.